# Ajuda com leitor de QR Code em Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic, qrcode

Estou tentando fazer o app (cordova + onsen) ler um QR Code e ao ler abrir o link contido no QR, mas ao invés dele abrir o link ele tenta abrir uma página na raiz do aplicativo (file://android_asset/www/barcode.result).

No código eu somente acrescentei o `var ref = window.open('barcode.result', '_blank');` o restante está funcionando normalmente, somente não abre o link contido no QR.

Segue meu código barcode controller:

```
app.controller('barcodeController', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.barcode = {
        'result': '',
        'format': '',
        'cancelled': ''
    };

    $scope.startScanner = function() {
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.barcode = {
                    'result': result.text,
                    'format': result.format,
                    'cancelled': result.cancelled
                }
                var ref = window.open('barcode.result', '_blank'); //parte acrescentada
            });
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    )};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ref = window.open(barcode.result, '_blank');
```

sem `''` ao referenciar a variável `barcode.result`

Comment: Eu tentei, mas ai nada acontece, ele volta para a tela com o botão para fazer o scan do QR...

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer funcionar, o que estava faltando era guardar o resultado do QR em uma variável e depois utilizar o resultado dessa variável para abrir o site.

Answer (score 0):

Boas, utilize o terminal, navegue até a pasta do seu aplicativo cordova e instale o plugin InAppBrowser:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Depois em seu código quando desejar abrir o browser do sistema utilize o target `_system`

```
window.open('http://google.com', '_system');
```

ou

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_system"> abrir browser do sistema </a>
```